# port forwarding with PIA (Private Internet Access)

Tags: minecraft, vpn, portforwarding

I am trying to make a minecraft server with PIA (private internet access). they have this function called "port forwarding". but when I try to use the generated port that PIA gives me, every port checker would say the port is closed. I have tried putting the local port to 25565 (minecraft default port) but then minecraft would say :

`[12:40:51] [Server thread/WARN]: **** FAILED TO BIND TO PORT! [12:40:51] [Server thread/WARN]: The exception was: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind [12:40:51] [Server thread/WARN]: Perhaps a server is already running on that port?`

If you have any ideas that could help, please reply.

Answer (score 0):

The port is already in use. To fix it, you can :

- Change the port that you are using in the `server.properties` file
- Stop the other server which is running on `25565` port. For example, if you are on linux and you don't know which process is using it, use `fuser -k 25565/tcp`, which will kill the current process and that port.

Comment: it is in use by PIA. I set the local port (in the PIA settings) to 25565 because there are no tutorials on how to set PIA's system up I followed this: https://airvpn.org/forums/topic/9455-hosting-a-minecraft-server-with-airvpn/ and this here said that I should set (on their system) the local port to the minecraft port